# How to synchronize two arrays with different length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, synchronize

let's consider two arrays containing indices:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5...]
y = [0,3,6,9,12,...]
```

These arrays may have slightly different length, approximately up to 3 indices.
In this example let's assume that `len(x) = len(y) - 1`
I want to return synchronized x, which will be extended by that 1 entry so that these arrays still correspond to each other (x[n]=y[n]+3).
I came up with idea to use the np.searchsorted method, however it does not work:

```
def synchronize_array(self, arr: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    sync_idx = np.searchsorted(arr, BASE_ARR)
    sync_idx[sync_idx >= len(arr)] = len(arr) - 1
    return arr[sync_idx]
```

Sync_idx in this case are [0, n-1, n-1, n-1, ...]
Is there any approach which will make it possible to synchronize these arrays?

Comment: What value do you want to extended element in x to take?

Comment: It looks to me that `y[n]=3*x[n]`, not `x[n]=y[n]+3`.

Comment: these arrays are storing indices for other arrays. I cannot assume a fixed difference between y[n] and x[n]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by synchronized, but you can iterate over both of the arrays, filling the shortest with a default value with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
from itertools import zip_longest

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12]

xy = zip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=0)
print(list(xy))
```

Which produces

```
[(0, 0), (1, 3), (2, 6), (3, 9), (4, 12), (5, 0)]
```

Cheers!

Comment: well, I think it might help! Thanks ;)